# Typescript build task in VSCode on Windows 10 with Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-tasks

My VSCode settings (workspace settings in my case) are setup to use `bash` as the default terminal:

```
{
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\bash.exe"
}
```

I need this to be able to debug my app.

My `tasks.json` looks like that:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "./tsconfig.json",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So when I try to build my project / run the build task (i.e. `Ctrl + B`), I get the following error:

> > Executing task: tsc  -p "c:\PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT\tsconfig.json" <
>
> error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'c:\PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT\tsconfig.json'.
>
> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

If I disable `bash` in my settings an use the default Windows terminal, the build works fine.

I remember it working few VSCode updates ago, but it stopped working in the latest VSCode versions. Not sure how that's related.

Comment: Same here - although in the bash shell the path does not exist has all of the slashes removed:
error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'c:PATHTOMYPROJECTtsconfig.json'.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this for a while, but finally gave up on the built-in Typescript task and instead just used a custom task:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Typescript watch",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "tsc --watch",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```